# jQuery Getting Values of Selected Selectboxes (Display in real-time)

Tags: html, jquery, forms

I'm working on a jQuery input to get all the values of the selectboxes clicked on select options. When I click all the values after the first option, I am unable to see the selected values unless I go back and re-click the first option. What I'm trying to do is make it so each time an option is clicked, it automatically shows on a div or input value. Also, when unclicked, it will be removed.

My jQuery Code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#checku").change(function() { 
        var favorite = [];
        $.each($("input[type='checkbox']:checked"),        
      function(){            
            favorite.push($(this).val());
            $("#values").val(favorite.join(", "));
        });
    });
});
```

My Form HTML

```
<form id="formu"> 
<input type="text" id="values" name="values"> 
<ul>
  <li>Title One <input type="checkbox" id="checku" name="checku[]" value="1"></li>
  <li>Title Two <input type="checkbox" id="checku" name="checku[]" value="2"></li>
  <li>Title Three <input type="checkbox" id="checku" name="checku[]" value="3"></li>
  <li>Title Four <input type="checkbox" id="checku" name="checku[]" value="4"></li>
 <li>Title Five<input type="checkbox" id="checku" name="checku[]" value="5"></li>
 <li>Title Six <input type="checkbox" id="checku" name="checku[]" value="6"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Change the IDs and Change the ID based `#..` selector. And it will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, like the comments `IDs` should be unique!

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    var favorite = [];
    $.each($("input[type='checkbox']:checked"),
      function() {
        favorite.push($(this).val());
        $("#values").val(favorite.join(", "));
      });
    if ($("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length == 0) {
      $("#values").val('')
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formu">
  <input type="text" id="values" name="values" />
  <ul>
    <li>Title One
      <input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="checku[]" value="1" />
    </li>
    <li>Title Two
      <input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="checku[]" value="2" />
    </li>
    <li>Title Three
      <input type="checkbox" id="check3" name="checku[]" value="3" />
    </li>
    <li>Title Four
      <input type="checkbox" id="check4" name="checku[]" value="4" />
    </li>
    <li>Title Five
      <input type="checkbox" id="check5" name="checku[]" value="5" />
    </li>
    <li>Title Six
      <input type="checkbox" id="check6" name="checku[]" value="6" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

I binded the event to the `input`. But if you want, you can change it to a specific group of `inputs`, for example adding the class `titles` to the `ul` and doing `$('.titles input[type='checkbox']')` as the selector.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Got to keep reminding myself of these simple things!

Comment: @mahatmanich it came out some months ago I think. it's a nice feature

Comment: @JoelAlmeida Use the tidy button on that to have nice code! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

Use jquery [`.map()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)

and

IDs must be unique in the DOM, you can use `.class` for the same.

```
 $(".checku").change(function() { 
     var favourite = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").map(function(i,chk){            
         return chk.value;
     }).get().join(",");
     $("#values").val(favourite);
});
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wkueLn7g/1/)